# Access 2007 - can I check record set with macro?

Tags: ms-access, macros

The menu page for my database has a series of buttons, each with a macro which runs a query to find the specific record set the user needs then opens the form to display the records. If there are no records returned then only the form header is being seen - the usual tab control and subforms aren't there. Is there a way from within the macro that I can test if the query results in no records? If so then I could use a MsgBox to let the user know what's going on.

Comment: When you say macros, do you mean VBA?

Comment: Currently the button click event is RunMacro, which then has an OpenQuery to find the recordset and an OpenForm to launch the main form. I suppose I could change it from the macro to go to VBA code if that would be simpler, as long as I could still open the form as well as run the query.

Comment: I usually find VBA easier, it gives you more control. You can run a query with [docmd.openquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238028(v=office.12).aspx), and open a form with [docmd.openform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx). You may find an easier way of doing the whole thing when you explore OpenForm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, you can do something on these lines:

```
If DCount("ID","MyQuery")=0 Then
    MsgBox "No records"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, Remou. This worked so perfectly that I've been able to rework some popup forms on another of my databases as well. Thanks as ever for the help.

Answer (score 0):

recordset.count, is a property you could use if available to the macro

or a conditional you could write as

if recordset.EOF then
  something()
else